# Java method not running in another file

Tags: java, class, methods

Here is the file that contains the method:

```
package getmethodical;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GetMethodical {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    // Validate INT input and checks if it's in range
    public static int getRangedInt(Scanner pipe, String prompt, int low, int high){
        System.out.println("Inside getRangedInt");
        System.out.println(prompt);
        String trash = "";
        int value = -5;
        boolean flag = false;

        while(!flag){
            if(pipe.hasNextInt()){
                value = pipe.nextInt();
                pipe.nextInt();
                if(value >= low && value <= high){
                    flag = true;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Please enter a number from 0 to 100");
                }
            }else{
                trash = pipe.nextLine();
                System.out.println(trash + " is not a valid input, please enter a number");
                pipe.nextLine();
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

In in another java file I'm trying to call the method:

```
package getmethodical;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class BirthDateTime {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner pipe = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Year
        String prompt = "Enter input: ";
        int high = 10;
        int low = 0;
        GetMethodical.getRangedInt(pipe, prompt, low, high);
    }

}
```

I want to call getRangedInt which is a class in one java main file in another java main file. When I do run the 2nd block, it runs successful but it doesn't call the method.

When I call the method in the main class of the file it's established in and then call it in another file it works.. This is really confusing to write over text so please let me know if there's anything else you need

Comment: Define "it doesn't call the method". If it's running without exceptions then it's calling whatever it thinks the method is based on the run environment classpath.

Comment: @DaveNewton the first line of text is printing something and it doesn't get printed so I assume the class I'm calling is either called inaccurately or i'm missing a fundamental.

Comment: Your code is running fine in my eclipse. what's the error or exception message? Output i got "Inside getRangedInt Enter input: "

Comment: This is what a debugger is for.  Please spend some time learning how to use it.  It will help you in the long run.

Comment: I suspect the latter--missing a fundamental. You're probably not running the most recent version of the class. How are you running it? If you're not getting an exception, then the method is being called and run--the questions are what version of the method is being called and run, and how is your runtime environment handling console IO.

Comment: @yangsun Thats really odd.. it says it ran successful but I dont get anything in the console

Comment: @Gprice1148 i bet you were running main method of  GetMethodical instead of main method of BirthDateTime

Comment: @yangsun I just created a new project. Two files, made a simple method in one and called it in another and it worked. Made a new project, moved all this code still nothing.. im confusing myself

Comment: @Gprice1148 remove your main method from GetMethodical

Answer (score 0):

your main method is having 
`Scanner pipe = new Scanner(System.in);`
This will expect an input from the console. comment out this line and hard code this pipe value for the below method to see u r getting anything as output.
`GetMethodical.getRangedInt(<some value>, prompt, low, high);`